# How do you make a minecart move?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm getting confused on how to make the minecart move. What do I need to do?

Comment: You put it on a rail, create a track (a path of rails) and push it. | I have no clue how to put this as a proper not-low-quality answer.

Comment: @aytimothy that is one way, there is also the answer below, and also "The player can slowly move the minecart forwards while riding it, by pressing forward" as said on the Wiki.

Answer (score 2):

"An external impulse may be needed to make the minecart start moving. The player can slowly move the minecart forwards while riding it, by pressing forward."

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecart

You need to make a rail track made up of any type of rail.
When you are inside the minecart, you can press the forward button to move. You can also use the powered rail as the tracks, so that when you give it a redstone signal(Say a redstone torch beside it) it will go forward.

Answer (score -3):

You should use a [Powered Rail](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Powered_Rail). By placing a redstone torch (or any source of redstone power) next to the rail, it will propel carts forward.